# how to authenticate processes?

Tags: c++, c, authentication

i want particular functions can be called by only some trusted-apps in C or C++.

For example, foo() can be called in app A or B but will failed to be called in app C.

I thought about using program names or PID or hash value of exe, but PID differ every execution and program name(argv[0]) can be different by path. Hash value of exe is unique value, but doesn't seem like a good approach(exe file is large).
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you aware of `class` in `C++` ?

Comment: Which operating system do you planing to use ?

Comment: reliable authentication isn't a simple thing. You could implement some challenge-response mechanism for example. Definitely "too broad" here.

Comment: Is depends how far you are willing to go. You can for example implement an IPC or socket communication to authenticate the process and then provide access to functions.

Comment: You can sign your executables, and check those signatures.

Comment: How is your function called at all? Is it compiled into a DLL? Or a static library? Or is it called using IPC?

Comment: operating system is LINUX and function will be called by static library

Answer (score 0):

You basically need Intel SGX or something similar. It's not for the fainthearted; this requires serious cryptography.

The idea of identifying your caller is called "attestation" in this context.